# Opening a PDF from a link in a new tab

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to open a PDF file in a new tab (or window depending on the browser config).
Currently if I specify the href for a local file it works as expected, but I need to provide a link that dynamically generated by an API.

So basically:
`<a href="/assets/test.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>`--> this works (opens the file in a new tab)

`<a href="https://my-pdf-url" target="_blank">PDF</a>`--> this opens a new window, closes it immediately and download the file.

I believe this is a security measure by the browser, but is there any way to get around this behavior and show it in a new tab?

Comment: The site you're loading the file from must be sending a `content-disposition: attachment` header, which forces the browser to download the file.

Comment: Possible solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270793/angular-2-how-to-display-pdf-file

Comment: @RichardDeeming it does not include that header but includes ```content-type: binary/octet-stream``` and I believe it should include ```application/pdf; charset=UTF-8```. Unfortunately I have no control over the API that returns the file or the link

Comment: @glx My first attempt to fetch the file contents and convert it to Blob with the correct content-type gave me a CORS error on the API.

Comment: That would do it - the browser doesn't understand what file type is being returned, so it offers to download the file for you. If you can't get the third-party to fix their API, and the CORS headers prevent you from loading the file in Javascript, I suspect you'll need some sort of proxy handler on your own server to retrieve the file and return it with the correct headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS window.open to open the PDF in a new tab:

```
    <a onclick='window.open("https://the_URL_here.somewhere.some","_blank")'>Open PDF in a new tab</a>
```

Or call a function that runs the window.open command. Another way would be to generate the link and add it to a layer using getElementById() using the innerHTML property.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it has the same result

Comment: I see. The code works. However, you need to send a specific response header to make the browser behave like you want:

Content-Disposition : inline

However, if you can't, the solution linked in the comments might do it.