# display in a new tab a pdf recieved from http response in Angular

Tags: angular, rest, http

I'm recieving a pdf as ResponseEntity<> that its a call I must do from a java api with the following endpoint link that I checked it works in Postman http://localhost:8093/api/recibirPDF (I can see the pdf ins postman), this endpoint is a file it's a pdf file, what i'm trying to do it's display this pdf in a new tab so the client could download it

I checked these:

- [Angular 2 how to display .pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270793/angular-2-how-to-display-pdf-file)
- [How to get PDF through API in angular service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332447/how-to-get-pdf-through-api-in-angular-service)

But is not working for me I would need a guide on how to approach
I have the resquest like this in the service:

```
    recibirPDF(): any{
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseURL + '/recibirPDF'}`, {responseType: 'application/pdf'}).subscibe(
    //TODO (receive pdf so i can show it in a new tab)
data => console.log('request done')
    );
    }
```

When I launch the app it works without errors even the console.log('request done')

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make any http call. Simply by using below code should open a new tab.

```
window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
```

Comment: I need make the call because the pdf it's genetared in the backend so I need to call the api in order to receive the pdf file

Comment: You mentioned the above API directly returns you the PDF so why do you want to make that call through Angular. I would suggest you to try simply running this URL in one of the tabs and see.

Comment: wow I did not noticed that, it works fine now...thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it resolved your issue. Thanks

Comment: I have not enough reputation to validate your answer sorry