# Embed tag calling URL multiple times in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe, angular8

I am trying to design a PDF viewer to show the PDF from the API response. The issue I am facing is the API is getting called multiple times like around 50 - 60 times or sometimes more. This is happening when I am trying to show the PDF only. If I add any website's link that is being called only 1 time. This issue is happening with both `iframe` and `embed`. I've tried 2 different solutions mentioned below and two of them calls the API multiple times but with different status code.

The full path is being retrieved from a API. The URL is like this `http://localhost:4200/upload/training/getMedia?path=<FULL PATH TO PDF>`. The JAVA server creates the BLOB and sends as response.

Tried Solution 1:

```js
sanitizeURL(URL: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(encodeURIComponent(URL));
}
```

Unsafe URL error coming using this approach like below -

[image: Error 1]

Tried Solution 2:

Reference solution - [Angular 2 how to display .pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43803616/13033071). Note here, the solution using **ng2-pdf-viewer** is not working. Its throwing `pdf-viewer` is not registered in module. Altough it's registered.

```js
async sanitizeURL(url: string) {
  try {
    const BLOB = await this.fetchTraining.getMedia(url).toPromise();
    const sanitize = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([BLOB], {type:'application/pdf'})));
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, sanitize);
  } catch(error) { console.log(error) }
}
```

Multiple times API getting called using this approach like below -

[image: Error 2]

For both the solution, the HTML is same like below:

```html
<div *ngIf="condition_true">
    <embed [attr.src]="sanitizeURL(url+list.path)" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">
</div>
```

---

Apart from these I also tried directly passing the URL in `src` like below -

```html
<div *ngIf="condition_true">
    <embed [attr.src]="url+list.path" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">
</div>
```

This resulted in the same Solution 2 error but the error only came 1 time.

How can this be solved? I am using Angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the source url on every template update. Try setting it as property on the component. E.g.

```
@Component({
    template: `<embed attr.src="{{this.url}}" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">`
})
export class MyCoolComponent {
    constructor(){
        this.url = this.sanitizeUrl(URL)
    }

    sanitizeUrl(url: string){
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(encodeURIComponent(URL));
    }
}
```